# Map Fragment inside another fragment causes Activity to crash

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using a Tabbed activity and in first fragment i am using map fragment.It is working all right but the problem is if i change between other fragment in this activity, whole activity crashes. After removing the map fragment the code runs well.But i want to put a map inside the fragment so please help.Here is my xml code for map fragment

```
     <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
```

This is the error every time before activity crashes-

```
    Process: com.gjs.finalproject, PID: 5571
                                             android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:767)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
                                                 at com.gjs.finalproject.HomeFragment.About2Fragment.onCreateView(About2Fragment.java:64)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1468)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:791)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:275)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:775)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:588)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #30: Duplicate id 0x7f0e009f, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0e009d with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2422)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:177)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:729)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418) 
                                                 at com.gjs.finalproject.HomeFragment.About2Fragment.onCreateView(About2Fragment.java:64) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1468) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:791) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:275) 
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:775) 
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:588) 
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557) 
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:761) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Here is my fragment code

```
   @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
      mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mapFragment != null) {
        //mMap = null;
        mapFragment=null;
        }
    }

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), lat + "   " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    LatLng locations = new LatLng(Util.reslatitude,Util.reslogitide);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locations, 13));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("abc")

            .position(locations));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post your logcat output?

Comment: refer using android:class

Comment: share your fragment code which has the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than initialize your mapFragment in `onActivityCreated`  initialize it on `onCreateView`

```
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
          mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
      }
```

And your `onActivityCreated` should be

```
   @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

add the following code, let me know if it works

```
   @Override
   public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(mapFragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

Comment: how did you start the fragment ? I mean did you replace or add . I suggest you to start your fragment like this   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container,new MapFragment(),"MapFragment")
                        .commit();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of map fragment try to use [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) within your first fragment.